# Java byte array sent with contentType: application/octetstream losing negative byte values

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, utf-8, binary

I have an array of integers in java, and I am converting it to a ByteArray

```java
public byte[] intArrayToByteArray(int[] arr) {

    // create byte buffer
    ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length*4);

    // create a view of the byte buffer as a int buffer
    IntBuffer intBuf = byteBuf.asIntBuffer();
    intBuf.put(arr);

    return byteBuf.array();
}
```

turns an array like this `[27759020,27682392]`
into a byte array like this:

`[1,-89,-111,-84,1,-90,102,88]`

This seems all good to me, the problem is when I send data over in a multipart formdata response (using Content-Type: application/octet-stream).

I'm using `MultipartEntityBuilder` to build the response in my servlet like this

```
MultipartEntityBuilder mpBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
mpBuilder.setBoundary("--boundary");

mpBuilder.addTextBody("meta", json,  ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
mpBuilder.addBinaryBody("HeightMap", bytes);

HttpEntity multipartData = mpBuilder.build();

try(OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
    multipartData.writeTo(out);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error(" --- Failed writing multipart form data to response. ---");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I get a string of string encoded values like this.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="HeightMap"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

����fX
```

which decodes in javascript to `[1, 65533, 65533, 65533, 1,65533, 102, 88]`

the function used to decode the string is here

```js
private static toUint8Array(dataString: string) {
    let byteArr = new Uint8Array(dataString.length);
    for(let i=0; i < dataString.length; i++) {
        let byte = dataString.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
        byteArr[i] = byte;
    }
    return byteArr;
}
```

(the value gets clamped in this function to 253 from 65533 but originally that's what `.charCodeAt(i)` gives)

you can see that each of the negative byte values from Java have been replaced by the UTF-8 'unknown character' value: 65533.

Is it possible to use another type of character encoding that will preserve the values of my bytes? Can I turn off the unknown value replacement that UTF-8 encoding does?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your JavaScript code. There is no character encoding for binary data; if you're having utf8 in your JavaScript code somewhere, you're using the wrong JavaScript cide

Comment: Also show your java code that generates the header/data- what is it? Email? Http response?

Comment: And please show the code that calls `intArrayToByteArray` and returns it as an HTTP response.  You aren’t trying to turn it into a String, are you?

Comment: added more of the generating code, let me know if you need more information

Comment: The xhr response comes as a large string

Comment: Javascript strings use UTF-16, so by the time `toUint8Array()` is called, binary data received into the `dataString` parameter has already been lost. Where is the Javascript code that receives the MIME data and parses it into a `string`?  Binary data is not character data, so you shouldn't be putting it as-is into a `string` in the first place. Since you are processing the data in Javascript, you might consider using Base64 to encode the binary bytes within the MIME data so they are transmitted in a textual format. The you can decode the Base64 back to binary on the receiving end

Comment: It seems that using multipart form data causes the response to be turned into a string, because I'm pulling that variable straight from the xhr.response object.